# A synonym for "take a small amount of something"

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, nouns

I'm writing about the structure of a reaction vessel used in scientific labs.  The vessel has a large container equipped with another component.  This another component is used for **taking a small amount of** the content of the container.  The content is a liquid mixture.  The component is not a sampler; it is for transferring the small amount to the next step of reaction.

I need to name the component.  The name should be a single phrase, something like **"...ing component"** or **"...er**" (like "dividing component""divider").

Does anybody have a good idea for this?? Thank you!

Comment: What sort of contents are in the container?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out!  I've edited the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: The component could be 'pipetting' from the container.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm wondering if "pipeting" defines the shape of the component as a pipet-like one.  The shape of the component is not mentioned, so I want to stay away from limiting the shape. Can I still use the word?

Comment: After seeing smatterer's answer, I'd use aliquot, as it has less definition on the shape.

Comment: Two votes for aliquoting.  Thank you!  Do you have any resources that support the use of aliquoting for once-only cases? I couldn't find any at this point.

Comment: In the 2013 Australian Chemistry Olympiad Paper, it was stated 'Tracey takes 10.00 mL aliquot of this solution'.

Comment: Thank you!! Your comments have been so quick and helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Aliquoting device**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aliquot) is probably the appropriate word for something that divides up the bulk material into smaller parts for further processing or analysis.

Comment: Thank you!
I wanted to use "aliquoting", but I found a difinition like this: "dividing something into smaller **portions** with the same quantity".

In my case, the action occurs only once and does not divide the content into small portions.  Can I still use this word?

Comment: Yes it can apply for a once-only device but in that case you can also use "sampler".  Is there a reason for not wanting to use "sampler"? It seems to be the better word to me.

Comment: Yes, I have a reason.  I've already used the noun "sample" to refer to a specimen.  The noun "sample" appears many times in the same paragrah, so I'd like to use a different word for the verb to make a clear distinction.  And, I can't simply change the noun "sample" to "specimen" because this document uses these two words to refer to different ideas.

Comment: I'm thinking to use "aliquoting device".  Is there any reference indicating that "aliquoting" can also be used for once-only cases?

Comment: If you google “aliquoting device” you’ll get patents for a bunch of them.  Aliquoting implies that the *quantity* taken is controlled but doesn’t imply anything about the *number* of lots taken. If it important to stress that this is a once-only aliquot, you will need to say that explicitly.

Comment: I'll do the search.  Your quick and helpful answers have helped my work.  Thank you so much!!